# How is this an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I wrote this program for an intro to comp sci class. All it is is a demonstration of using a while loop. My professor marked this program as having an infinite loop, but I don't understand how it is an infinite loop because it terminates when -1 is entered.

```
int main() {

int accountNum, balance, totalOfItems, totalOfCredits, creditLimit; //Integers for the user to input

while (accountNum != -1)
{
    cout << "Enter account number" << endl;
    cin >> accountNum;
    cout << "Enter balance" << endl;
    cin >> balance;
    cout << "Enter total of all items charged this month" << endl;
    cin >> totalOfItems;
    cout << "Enter total of all credits applied to the account this month" << endl;
    cin >> totalOfCredits;
    cout << "Enter credit limit" << endl;
    cin >> creditLimit;

    int newBalance = balance + totalOfItems - totalOfCredits;

    if (newBalance > creditLimit)
    {
        cout << "Account Number: " << accountNum << "\nCredit Limit: " << creditLimit << "\nNew Balance " << newBalance << endl;
        cout << "Credit limit exceeded." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "New balance : " << newBalance << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you ask your professor?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I think you're right. This loop can terminate.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Could be that the autograder saw your code keeps going after account number -1 is entered (which is definitely a bug) and interpreted it as an infinite loop.

Comment: The first iteration has undefined behavior, so I suppose "infinite loop" is a possible manifestation of that (although it would take a particularly devious compiler to do this, I think).

Comment: Also, you're reading an uninitialized variable for the first execution of the loop test.

Comment: What will happen when someone enters "hello" ?

Comment: @user2357112 ah this is most likely the case, as I know he uses an autograder. Thank you everyone. I will also fix the bugs and resubmit. Appreciate it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code.

1. `accountNum` is not initialized, before it is used. This results in undefined behavior.
2. Even if `-1` is entered, the loop will still slog through, and all the remaining input must still be entered.
3. If invalid input is entered, `std::cin` enters error state, and will loop forever.

Answer (score 1):

The code shown *requires* an input of -1. If the input stream closes or encounters an error (such as typing a non-numeric value into one of the numbers), the value of -1 will never be received.

In addition to that, the while loop condition is only tested at the start of each loop iteration, it's not a guard test - so entering an account of -1 still requires you to type in all the remaining values.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the condition of -1 is never met within the loop.

I see the first entry:

```
cin >> accountNum;
```

I would assume this is never -1.

To end the loop, you would need to store the value on accountNum as -1 near the end of your loop's code.